# howto setup network printing cups

Tags: cups

Sorry to ask a very basic question, but I am completely lost with all this cups stuff, printing with linux used to be simple with lpd ...
What I would like to do:
I have several computers running different version of linux in my home-network.
On one machine (call it print-server) I have installed a driver with cups for a brother connected via LAN. This included downloading and installing the proprietary ppd-file etc.
Now on all other clients I just want to print via this print-server. And of course I don't want to go through the hassle of installing some ppd-files on every client - for me this abstraction is the main - if not only purpose of a print-server.
From what I understand, this is not possible with cups. Apparently cups requires me to install the 'driver' (ppd-file) on every client. And to make things worse this installation gets kicked out with virtually every update of centos.
Is my dream-world of printing really too simple or am I missing something? 
Many thanks for any kind of help/advice

Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using linux, the task should be easier. You just have to share the print queue on print-server, you can use `cupsctl --share-printer`. Since all other clients are connected to the server, the `cups-browsed` will be able to see the printer ( may require some changes in `cups-browsed.conf` file). It will automatically generate the ppd file and the printing should also work.